# Sendgrid category analytics with API v3

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

Is it possible to add a category tag to mail being send via the Sendgrid API?

What I'd like to know is open and click rates for specific types of transactional e-mails. It appears you can add a category using the STMP API but I can't find any documentation on how to do that using API v3 ([just a GET endpoint](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/api_v3.html)).

Am I even thinking about this right? Is SendGrid the right place to track opens and clicks or should I use the webhooks and track this stuff myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like SendGrid accepts categories. Check out their *other* [API documentation page](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/index.html).

There's also a send example of categories in [their python client](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/blob/master/examples/mail/mail.py#L52).